# How merge and sum values by comparing any one or two values of the same array

Tags: php, arrays

Below is the array in php and I need  function to solve n numbers of array as displayed in Expected result by summing the (2) and (3) values if (0) and (1) are matching :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Week - 1
                    [1] => 2019-08-05
                    [2] => 1
                    [3] => 2
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Week - 2
                    [1] => 2019-08-12
                    [2] => 3
                    [3] => 4
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Week - 3
                    [1] => 2019-08-19
                    [2] => 5
                    [3] => 6
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Week - 1
                    [1] => 2019-08-05
                    [2] => 7
                    [3] => 8
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Week - 2
                    [1] => 2019-08-12
                    [2] => 9
                    [3] => 10
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Week - 3
                    [1] => 2019-08-19
                    [2] => 11
                    [3] => 12
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Week - 4
                    [1] => 2019-08-26
                    [2] => 13
                    [3] => 14
                )

        )

)
```

Expected Result :

```
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Week - 1
                    [1] => 2019-08-05
                    [2] => 8
                    [3] => 10
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Week - 2
                    [1] => 2019-08-12
                    [2] => 12
                    [3] => 14
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Week - 3
                    [1] => 2019-08-19
                    [2] => 16
                    [3] => 18
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Week - 4
                    [1] => 2019-08-26
                    [2] => 13
                    [3] => 14
                )
```

Need help to get the above expected result for the raised query. I tried below code :

```
<?php
$sum = [];
foreach($weekly as $aSet) {
    foreach($aSet as $k => $kv) {
        $i = 0;
        foreach($kv as $v) {
            $sum[$k][$i] += $v;
            $i++;          
        }
    }
}
?>
```

But it will add all types :

```
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
                [1] => 4038
                [2] => 8
                [3] => 10
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
                [1] => 4038
                [2] => 12
                [3] => 14
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
                [1] => 4038
                [2] => 16
                [3] => 18
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
                [1] => 4038
                [2] => 13
                [3] => 14
            )
```

I want get sum only for 2 and 3rd value and need to keep constant for 0 and 1st value for exact match

Comment: Hi, what have you tried ?

Comment: Instead of `var_dump` or `print_r` output, can you show the `var_export` output of the arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because all your nested arrays are with predefined amount of elements, all of those with the same indexes, you can use a [`for`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) loop instead of the third `foreach`:

```
$sum = [];
foreach($weekly as $aSet)
{
    foreach($aSet as $k => $kv)
    {
        $sum[$kv[0]][0] = $kv[0];
        $sum[$kv[0]][1] = $kv[1];
        for($i = 2; $i <= 3; $i++)
        {
            $sum[$kv[0]][$i] += $kv[$i];
        }
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($sum);
echo "</pre>";
```

With a [`for`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) loop you can cycle inside the array considering only the needed elements of that array (in your case the indexes `0` and `1` aren't useful in this loop).

Output:

```
Array
(
    [Week - 1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Week - 1
            [1] => 2019-08-05
            [2] => 8
            [3] => 10
        )

    [Week - 2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Week - 2
            [1] => 2019-08-12
            [2] => 12
            [3] => 14
        )

    [Week - 3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Week - 3
            [1] => 2019-08-19
            [2] => 16
            [3] => 18
        )

    [Week - 4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Week - 4
            [1] => 2019-08-26
            [2] => 13
            [3] => 14
        )

)
```

If you prefer the array with numbered indexes do that:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r(array_values($sum));
echo "</pre>";
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Week - 1
            [1] => 2019-08-05
            [2] => 8
            [3] => 10
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Week - 2
            [1] => 2019-08-12
            [2] => 12
            [3] => 14
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Week - 3
            [1] => 2019-08-19
            [2] => 16
            [3] => 18
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Week - 4
            [1] => 2019-08-26
            [2] => 13
            [3] => 14
        )

)
```